# Where do we see Targets in Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4.2

Where do we see "Targets" in Xcode 4.2.

I want to see the headers, compiled files & libraries that are part of my project. I can see that in Xcode 3.2.6.

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click on the project file in the Project Navigator. You should see your Project and Targets list on the left pane. Click on the Build Phases tabs. Here, you can see your libraries (under "Link Binary with Libraries") and source files (under "Compile Sources").